# How do I define what happens when user enter's text in TextInput and presses enter in Kivy?

Tags: python, oop, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to create a simple Chatbot application UI using Kivy and Python but I'm stuck at the very first stage.
How do I access the TextInput widget inside the BoxLayout to fetch it's contents?

I read that the function *on_text_validate()* is called whenever you press 'Enter' on the TextInput. However this code down below doesn't seem to be functioning.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
#:import AnchorLayout kivy.uix.anchorlayout
#:import Layout kivy.uix.layout
<ChatBotScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        ScrollView:
            Label:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                text_size: self.width, None
                botOutput: root.botOutput
        ScrollView:
            Label:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                text_size: self.width, None
                userInput: root.userInput
        TextInput:
            id: ti_userinput
            multiline: False
''')

class ChatBotScreen(Screen):
    userInput = StringProperty()
    botOutput = StringProperty()

    def on_text_validate(self):
        text_input_userInput = self.ids['ti_userinput'].text
        self.ids['ti_userinput'].text = ''
        print(text_input_userInput)

    def UserInput(self):
        pass
    def BotOutput(self):
        pass

sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())
sm.add_widget(ChatBotScreen(name='mainchat'))    

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
```

Please guide me.

Comment: My question is: when do you want to get the text?

Comment: @eyllanesc I want the text fetched when we press Enter/ Return key after typing in the TextInput field. So each time the user does that, I want the value updated (function called).

Comment: What value do you want to be updated? What function do you mean?

Comment: @eyllanesc I want whatever is inside the on_text_validate function executed. So there I am storing the value of text in text_input_userInput variable, printing it and clearing the current TextInput text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your case is that `on_text_validate` is not a method of the `Screen` class, but of `TextInput`, so you will never call `on_text_validate` of the `ChatBotScreen` class, what you can do is invoke that method from the `on_text_validate` event of the `TextInput`:

```
Builder.load_string('''
#:import AnchorLayout kivy.uix.anchorlayout
#:import Layout kivy.uix.layout
<ChatBotScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        ScrollView:
            Label:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                text_size: self.width, None
                botOutput: root.botOutput
        ScrollView:
            Label:
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                text_size: self.width, None
                userInput: root.userInput
        TextInput:
            id: ti_userinput
            multiline: False
            on_text_validate: root.on_text_validate()
''')

class ChatBotScreen(Screen):
    userInput = StringProperty()
    botOutput = StringProperty()

    def on_text_validate(self):
        text_input_userInput = self.ids['ti_userinput'].text
        self.ids['ti_userinput'].text = ''
        print(text_input_userInput)

sm = ScreenManager(transition=FadeTransition())
sm.add_widget(ChatBotScreen(name='mainchat'))    

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Thank you so much for your help! If you don't mind, I have another slightly un-related but small question. How can I instantiate/create a widget using python code at a particular widget hierarchy? For example instantiate another Label inside the 2nd ScrollView? (To basically display the user's input like a chatbox message). Many thanks again!

Comment: @RhinoFreak I do not understand what you want, I recommend trying to solve it, find information, design and structure your code, and after doing all that involves a lot of time and effort just make a question, it will serve to strengthen your knowledge. :D